# Is suffix -red still active in word formation?

Tags: suffixes, productive-affixes

Etymonline defines  the suffix ***[-red](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-red#etymonline_v_55070)*** as a:

> word-forming element meaning "condition or state of," Middle English, from Old English -rede, from ræden "condition, rule, reckoning," a suffixed form of ræd "to advise, rule" (see rede). Common in Old English, less so in Middle English but still active in word-formation.

The terms I can think of ending -red with the meaning suggested above are very few, such as  *hatred* and *kindred*,  but there are certainly a few more.

So in what sense is suffix -red still active? If it really is.

Comment: You are almost certainly misinterpreting what Etymonline says. Changing the word order clears things up: they are saying that the suffix was "less [common] but still active in word-formation in Middle English", not that the suffix was "less [common] in Middle English but is still active in word-formation [now]". This interpretation is the only one which makes sense given that they explicitly say that this is a Middle English suffix (so presumably it didn't occur to them that someone could interpret their ambiguous word order as saying that it is still productive now).

Comment: @Pilcrow - if that is the case just VTC the question.

Comment: The question is perfectly meaningful and has already been answered satisfactorily, so I see no reason to vote to close. I'm just pointing out that it was instigated by a misunderstanding.

Comment: Take care that "etymonline" is just a crappy web site someone threw together to make a few ad banner dollars.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misinterpretation of a website's statement.

Answer (score 9):

The [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-red#etymonline_v_55070) link in your question says that suffix *-red* " is analogous to -hood, which has replaced it in brotherhood, neighborhood, etc.; it survives in about 25 words."

[Wiktionary's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_terms_suffixed_with_-red) list of words derived from -red consists of just 15 words, of which only two are common:

- [brothered](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brothered#English) (since replaced by *brotherhood)*
- [brotherred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brotherred#English) (since replaced by *brotherhood*)
- [cantred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cantred#English) (uncertain etymology)
- [ferede](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ferede#English)
- [folkred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/folkred#English)
- [gossipred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gossipred#English)
- [hatred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hatred#English)
- [hundred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hundred#English)
- [kindred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kindred#English)
- [latred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/latred#English)
- [manred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manred#English)
- [neighborred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neighborred#English)
- [neighboured](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neighboured#English)
- [sibberidge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sibberidge#English) (variant of *sibred*)
- [sibred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sibred#English)

With the exception of *cantred*, and *hundred* which has appeared on this list inexplicably, all of these words are formed from the Old English suffix -*reden*. None of them were coined recently by any stretch of the imagination; in no way is it an 'active' suffix, as Etymonline claims. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/red#:%7E:text=%2Dred,of%20nouns%3A%20hatred%3B%20kindred.) even says that it was only "formerly used in the formation of nouns."

Modern coinages are generally formed with *-hood*, *-dom*, or *-ship*, never *-red.* This is presumably because *kindred* and *hatred* are the only words in common usage that were formed from this root- its rarity means that few people even *know* that it's actually a suffix, and nobody's going to coin a word using a suffix that they're not aware of.

[This](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lexical_Semantics_and_Diachronic_Morphol/gsNjdT8iArQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22-red%20suffix%22%20hatred%20OR%20kindred&pg=PA192&printsec=frontcover) passage seems to hold the clue, but part of it's unfortunately cut off on Google Books. From the part of the book that *is* viewable online, the author says that the suffix was lost in the Middle English period. I can't see the whole argument, but she writes in the chapter's conclusion that "since a 'stronger' suffix had already existed for a long time, native *-ness*, formations with *-reden* were ousted by formations with *-ness.*"

Comment: I wonder if it fell out of favor due to confusion with the *-ed* suffix for past participles. Even though the root word is a noun, this combines with verbification. So e.g. "brothered" could mean "became a brother".

Answer (score 6):

Despite what Etymonline says, it is "no longer productive" (per [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-red)). That page also provides several words with the -red suffix, of which only "hundred" is common nowadays besides the two words that you provided. (Despite what another answer says, "hundred" uses the same suffix, which carries the meaning "to reckon" and related meanings. But see M-W's note on etymology [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kindred#h2), which discusses some uncertainty surrounding this suffix.)

Comment: The most recent such production may have been Sir Walter Scott's 1819 usage of *cousinred* in his *Rob Roy*, an intentional archaïsm e’en then, at II. xi. 237:  “‘There is some cousin-red between us, doubtless,’ said the Baillie reluctantly.” There are a few other Scotian usages in the 19th Century, but it has for most intents and purposes gone the way of all things.

Comment: "Despite what another answer says, "hundred" uses the same suffix, which carries the meaning "to reckon" and related meanings" - any citation for this part?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I didn't want to go deeply into it since that's not what the question is really about, but [Etymonline says](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hundred#etymonline_v_16062): The second element is Proto-Germanic *rath "reckoning, number" (as in Gothic raþjo "a reckoning, account, number," garaþjan "to count;" from PIE root *re- "to reason, count").

Comment: As mentioned in comments above, it's not clear if Etymonline is saying it was still productive in Middle English, or in modern English. Contextually, it must be the former.